# Forced unwrapping vs not

Tags: swift

Facebook recently updated Parse to support Swift. One of the code examples it gives is this:

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
gameScore.setObject(1337, forKey: "score")
gameScore.setObject("Sean Plott", forKey: "playerName")
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { 
(success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if success {
        NSLog("Object created with id: \(gameScore.objectId)")
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}
```

I'm curious about this part: "(success: Bool!, error: NSError!)", in particular the point of the exclamation marks. My understanding of optionals was something like this:

NSError: this is an NSError, and cannot be nil.
NSError?: this might include an NSError or it might be nil, but it needs to be unwrapped first.
NSError!: this is a force-unwrapped NSError?, and thus cannot be nil.

Facebook's example says that success is a Bool! and error is an NSError! - ie, they are both definitely provided. How come they aren't just written as Bool and NSError, providing that Facebook has unwrapped them before sending them on? Also, how can both success and error both be set? Traditional use of NSError would say that it's set to nil when there's no problem.

Comment: `!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, which behaves **exactly** like an optional just that you can access properties with having to unwrap it before hand. The downside is if you do that and its `nil`, you get an exception

Comment: when you see a parameter which is not optional (`!`), that means exactly what its name suggests: you can always assume that is a valid object and won't be `nil` anytime when your block is invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probabily due to interoperability with Objective-C APIs. Since any object can be `nil` in Objective-C, those two values have to be optional in Swift.

Anyway - since apparently they guarantee that those objects are never going to be `nil` - they can afford to implicitly unwrap them, allowing whoever uses this API to save a few unwraps, which is nice.

Concerning your statement

> Traditional use of `NSError` would say that it's set to nil when there's no problem.

This is just wrong, even in Objective-C.

The `BOOL`/`NSError` pattern in Cocoa dictates that you have to check the `success` value to know whether an error occured, and - if that's the case - then the `NSError` will contain information about it.

Checking for `NSError` to be `nil` is a common misuse of this pattern, and it can lead to logic errors in your code, as some Apple APIs return a non-`nil` error even in case of success.

Comment: Yes, I had wondered whether it was just an interop reason. I'm trying to think it through: is fair to say, then, that the ObjC method making this call back can pass in nil (because it's just passing in standard NSObjects), so the runtime part that joins the two will consider them optional parameters, and so the Facebook code force-unwraps them as a convenience to devs?

Comment: Also, you're right that my phrasing was very poor. I didn't mean to check nil and ignore success, and that is indeed a bad thing to do. What I meant was that I would expect error to be nil if the call was successful. In the Facebook case, if the call is successful, how can error be not-nil?

Comment: @FizzBuzz, imagine the _error_ as not an error but more like a _status report_. the 'successful' report is also a report, logically the same as the 'error' or the 'warning' would be. the 'successful' report usually the zero (`0`) _error-code_, which is entirely valid error as _no-error_.

Comment: `Obj-C` can pass technically `nil`, because there's no formal way of preventing it. The fact that they force the unwrap means that they know this won't be cause by the implementation. It's a formal guarantee you simply cannot express in Obj-C.

Concerning the non-nil error, it can simply be a `NSError` instance with an 'ok' code in it (like `0` or similar)

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook's example says that success is a Bool! and error is an NSError! - ie, they are both definitely provided.

yes, they are. bear in mind, the error code zero (`0`) usually marks the successful transactions, that is much more correct logically than sending `nil`.

> Also, how can both success and error both be set? Traditional use of NSError would say that it's set to nil when there's no problem.

that tells you (implicitly), if any error occurs, the `error` will *always* be provided for your block as valid error message.

Comment: It also tells you that `error` is *always* provided in any case.

Comment: obviously, yes, that is true. but normally you ignore the error message if transaction was successful, even it is provided.

Comment: agree that's the common pattern, but the guarantee is far from obvious. It's usually `nil` when no errors occur.

Comment: yes, I know. but here that seems far better why the error should not be optional at all; just imagine the opposite situation when the error would be optional here, you cannot be sure automatically the `error` is valid object, when the transaction is failed, and that is much worse situation (logically only – in my view) than having an 'extra' error object in case of success.